# Mobile Safari doesn't blend background gradient image to background color

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, background-image

I have a classic background image gradient, fading out to a given background colour, see http://fiddle.jshell.net/7msZ5/ for the code.

The problem is that, when viewed on Mobile Safari (version 5 on iPhone 4), the image doesn't successfully blend into the background colour, there's a visible line at the bottom where the image runs out and the background image should take over, view http://fiddle.jshell.net/7msZ5/show/ to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest extending the gradient image so that it will get to the gray earlier (so the gray is your exact desired shade instead of something that is 1 shade off), or using
`-webkit-gradient`  (some older browsers may not support it....)

example:

```
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ajzo0.jpg) rgb(145,127,103); /* Old browsers (in case they don't support webkit, use the original image. */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(145,127,103,1) 0%, rgba(236,235,233,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(145,127,103,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(236,235,233,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(145,127,103,1) 0%,rgba(236,235,233,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(145,127,103,1) 0%,rgba(236,235,233,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(145,127,103,1) 0%,rgba(236,235,233,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(145,127,103,1) 0%,rgba(236,235,233,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#917f67', endColorstr='#ecebe9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

yes, it is a lot more code, but it does get the work done.